# RestSharp infinitely adds User-Agent header until target API returns 400 - Bad Req - Headers too long

Tags: restsharp

I recently upgraded **RestSharp** to **107.3.0** in the hope to fix some connectivity issues (as mentioned in the documentation).

After 1 hour of being live on production with this upgrade, my targetted API started throwing **'400 Bad Request - Headers too long'**. A recycle was only a temporary fix.

When I use Fiddler to see my API calls (locally), I noticed that the **User-agent** header contains:

*RestSharp/107.3.0.0 RestSharp/107.3.0.0 RestSharp/107.3.0.0 (...)*

... and each next call adds the agent name to the growing header value until the header is, well, just too long.

Anyone else experienced this before?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was creating a RestClient(httpClient) object each time, but re-using the same HTTP client. Creating an instance of RestClient initializes some default headers, resulting in infinitely adding the user agent header value.

Re-using the RestClient as well, fixed the behavior.

Comment: There's a PR that adds a constructor for accepting an `HttpClient` issue and not changing anything there (no header, no timeout). It hasn't been merged yet. I will also try to fix this issue, it should be replacing the header, not adding it. But your solution is correct anyway.